# php mysql forms pass results from database to orignal form field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

I have an issue, all my methods work but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to echo the results of an sql query back to the original form field line per piece of query information. Below is the sample of my code.

P.S. I tried to echo the original table in the bottom of the sql code using a variable to hold the relevant data but it simply creates a duplicate form table at the bottom of my page. see code

```
<html>
<title> Student Main Record:</title>
<center><b><font size="15"><u>Student Main Record</center></font></b><br><BR></u>
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
<table align="center" width="90%" border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0"><center><font size="6"><b>Student Information:</center</table></font>                
<table border="0">
    <tr><td>Panther ID</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="7" name="PID"></td></tr>                        
    <tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="firstName"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Middle Name</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="middleName"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="lastName"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Age</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="3" name="age"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gender</td><td><input type="radio" checked name="Gender" value="Female">Female <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male">Male</td></tr>
<tr><td>Country</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="30" name="country"></td></tr>              
    </td></tr></tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>   
        <tr></tr>                           
        <tr><td>Address1</td><td><input type="text" value=""  size="50" maxlength="50" name="add1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address2</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="add2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>City</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="city"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>State</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="state"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Zip Code</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="10" name="zip"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Primary Tel #</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="20" name="tel1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Secondary Tel #</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="20" name="tel2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="email"></td></tr>                      
</table>
</td>
    <td>
<table width="100%" border="0">
            </table>                    
   <table border="0"><br><br>
   <tr><font size=5pt><center>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspEmergency Contact Information:</tr></font></center><tr><tr><tr><tr><Tr><tr></tr></tr></tr>
    <tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="ECfirstName"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Middle Name</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="ECmiddleName"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="EClastName"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Age</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="3" name="ECage"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Gender</td><td><input type="radio" checked name="Gender1" value="Female">Female <input type="radio" name="Gender1" value="Male">Male</td></tr>
<!--    <tr><td>Social Security</td><td><input type="text" size="50" maxlength="10" name="ECss">-->
<tr><td>Country</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="30" name="ECcountry"></td></tr>
</td></tr></tr>
    </tr>
        <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>   
        <tr></tr>                           
        <tr><td>Address1</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="ECadd1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Address2</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="ECadd2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>City</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="ECcity"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>State</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50" name="ECstate"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Zip Code</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="10" name="ECzipCode"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Primary Tel #</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="20" name="ECtel1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Secondary Tel #</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="20" name="ECtel2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="text" value="" size="50" maxlength="50"    name="ECemail"></td></tr>                     
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
    <tr><br>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="find" value="Find">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
<input type="submit" name="modify" value="Modify">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
</td>
</tr>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

PHP code below - each method works but I want to echo them back to populate the original form field above.

```
if (!empty($_POST['save']))
{

$connection = mysqli_connect("xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx");
  // Check connection
        if (!$connection)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
       else

        //select a database
            $dbName="spr14_aglic006";
            $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection,$dbName); 
            //confirm connection to database
          if (!$db_selected) 
          {
die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysqli_error());
          }
            mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO students 
             (StudentID,
              FirstName,
              LastName, 
              MiddleName,
              Address1,
              Address2,
              City,
              State,
              Country,
              Zip,
              Telephone1,
              Telephone2,
              ECFirstName,
              ECLastName,
              ECMiddleName,
              ECAddress1,
              ECAddress2,
              ECCity,
              ECState,
              ECCountry,
              ECZip,
              ECTelephone1,
              ECTelephone2)
            VALUES
            ('".$_POST['PID']."',
             '".$_POST['firstName']."',
             '".$_POST['lastName']."',
             '".$_POST['middleName']."',
             '".$_POST['add1']."',
             '".$_POST['add2']."',
             '".$_POST['city']."',
             '".$_POST['state']."',
             '".$_POST['country']."',
             '".$_POST['zip']."',
             '".$_POST['tel1']."',
             '".$_POST['tel2']."',
             '".$_POST['ECfirstName']."',
             '".$_POST['EClastName']."',
             '".$_POST['ECmiddleName']."',
             '".$_POST['ECadd1']."',
             '".$_POST['ECadd2']."',
             '".$_POST['ECcity']."',
             '".$_POST['ECstate']."',
             '".$_POST['ECcountry']."',
             '".$_POST['ECzipCode']."',
             '".$_POST['ECtel1']."',
             '".$_POST['ECtel2']."')");
             echo "Record created.";
            mysqli_close($connection);
}





if (!empty($_POST['find']))
{

$connection = mysqli_connect("xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx");
 // Check connection
        if (!$connection)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

          $dbName="spr14_aglic006";
            mysqli_select_db($connection,$dbName) or die(mysqli_error());


$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM students WHERE StudentID='".$_POST['PID']."'");
if (!$result)
{echo"No record found" . mysqli_error($connection);}


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo $row['StudentID'] . " " . $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'] . " " . 
                     $row['MiddleName'] . " " . $row['Address1'] . " " . $row['Address2'] . " " . 
                     $row['City'] . " " . $row['State'] . " " . $row['Country'] . " " . 
                     $row['Zip'] . " " . $row['Telephone1'] . " " . $row['Telephone2'] . " " . 
                     $row['ECFirstName'] . " " . $row['ECLastName'] . " " . $row['ECMiddleName'] . " " . 
                     $row['ECAddress1'] . " " . $row['ECAddress2'] . " " . $row['ECCity'] . " " . 
                     $row['ECState'] . " " . $row['ECCountry'] . " " . $row['ECZip'] . " " . 
                     $row['ECTelephone1'] . " " . $row['ECTelephone2'];
                mysqli_close($connection);
            }

}


if (!empty($_POST['modify']))
{
 $connection = mysqli_connect("xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx");
  // Check connection
        if (!$connection)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
        else
        {
            //select table
            $dbName="spr14_aglic006";
            mysqli_select_db($connection,$dbName) or die(mysqli_error());
            echo "Database Found! <br>";

            $query =("UPDATE students
SET FirstName='".$_POST['firstName']."', LastName='".$_POST['lastName']."'
WHERE StudentID='".$_POST['PID']."'");

            $res = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

            if ($res)
            {
               echo "<p>Record Updated<p>";
            }   
            else
            {
               echo "Problem updating record. MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($connection);
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($connection);
}






if (!empty($_POST['delete']))
{

 $connection = mysqli_connect("xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx");

        // Check connection
        if (!$connection)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
        else
        {
            //select table
            $dbName="spr14_aglic006";
            mysqli_select_db($connection,$dbName) or die(mysqli_error());
            echo "Database Found! <br>";      
$sql =("DELETE FROM students WHERE StudentID='".$_POST['PID']."'");

            $retval = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
            if($retval)
            {
              echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
            }
           else
           echo "Record not found";           
            }
mysqli_close($connection);
}
echo '<center><b><font size="15"><u>Student Main Record</center></font></b><br><BR></u>
<tr><td>Panther ID</td><td><input type="text" value=".$PID." size="50" maxlength="7"></td></tr>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are submitting the form to same page which is fine. If so, first declare your variables and move your sql above your form. Then for each form field, do the following:

```
if(isset($_POST[PID]){
    $pid = $_POST[PID];
}else{
    $pid = "";
}
```

In your html, put each variable in the value of the associated form element, so that it displays if the form has been submitted or its empty if the form has not been submitted.

```
<input type="text" value="$pid" size="50" maxlength="7" name="PID">
```